# Connect virtual switch to multiple physical networks

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-8.1

Recently I set up a few Hyper-V servers on my windows 8.1 (Pro) laptop. I connected all of them to a single virtual switch. Now I want to connect the virtual switch to the physical network (instead of creating an external switch for internet access) to solve 3 problems:

- I have to to use as few IP addresses as possible in my physical network at home
- If I connect to an external network directly, my VMs would get different IPs on any network I connect
  to (I dont use it at home only) and I need to have a static IP for my VMs.
- In my laptop there are 2 network adapters and I have to use both of them.

I already tried to share the connection of both physical adapters with the virtual switch but it didn't work because windows automatically disables the other one every time I try to share a second connection.

Is this possible on windows? If yes, what do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the right way to solve your problem is to first team the NICs in your machine and then attach the virtual switch to the team.  NIC teaming, however, is only natively supported in Windows Server, not Windows Pro, so your only option is to find a NIC teaming setup created by somebody (not Microsoft) who supports this in a client OS.  I don't know if such a thing even exists.

The virtual switch definitely only supports one connection to a physical network, either a NIC or a team.  You can't attach two physical NICs separately.